Power BI Date and if
So the scenario I'm looking to achieve is.
If [future date](Already a column) matches [Todays] date and [Balance](Already a column) = 1 Then 'Yes' otherwise 'N'
Does anyone know the best DAX Formula to do this ?
This is my first try at date formulas.

you can try this
column = if ( [future day]=today() && [Balance]=1, "Yes","No")

This has resolved it, thank you !
